# Magento2, placing the custom block in header of order creation page in admin panel

Tags: magento2, layout, sales-order, backend

I tried to add a custom block to header of order creation page in admin panel. Below code in my module did not work!

In file */app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml*:

```
 <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Order\Msg" name="msg" template="MyVendor_MyModule::order/msg.phtml" before="page.actions.toolbar"/>
 </referenceContainer>
```

Edit 1: As requested in comment I share the code but nothing special there, here is block:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Adminhtml\Order;


class Msg extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\AbstractCreate
{

 protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

    }

    /**
     * Get header text
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    } 

}
```

And template file:

```
<?php echo $block->getHeaderText(); ?>
```

Edit 2: It works for other part of the page like before item grids but header!

Comment: please share the block and template code

Comment: Block is just displaying msg, nothing special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below worked :)

```
<referenceContainer name="header">
          <block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Order\Msg" name="msg" template="MyVendor_MyModule::order/msg.phtml" before="page.actions.toolbar"/>
</referenceContainer>
```